# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, django

when i am trying to implement class view it showing the below error
Thanks in Advance
**views.py----**

```
 - from re import template import django from django.shortcuts import
   render from django.views.generic import ListView from .models import
   Post
   
   def PostListView(ListView):
       model = Post
       template_name = 'blog/home.html'
       context_object_name = 'posts'
       ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

**urls.py-----**

```
 - from django.urls import path from .views import PostListView from .
   import views
   
   urlpatterns = [
       path('', PostListView.as_view(),name="blog-home"),
       path('about/', views.about,name="blog-about"), ]
```

**error------**

```
 - return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/Users/kundan/Documents/CodeHub/Python Framework/DjangoWeb/blogspot/blog/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
           path('', PostListView.as_view(),name="blog-home"),
       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a `function`, but you should define a `class`.

```
def PostListView(ListView):
    ...

# change to:

class PostListView(ListView):
    ...
```

Remember, that `classes` inherit another `classes` in their `()`, but `functions` recieve variables to use inside them. It is similar in some way, but very different in usage.